# How to issue several commands to an existing bash Process?

Tags: java, linux, shell, process

I am making a simple GUI interface for a TUI Minecraft server, I need to issue commands to that program based on GUI events (button clicked etc...). I created a process builder but how would I give the running program more commands.

An example of what I am trying to accomplish is opening a command-line program in Java, and the program asks for my name. My question is, how do I give that program my name.

I have looked at many preexisting Stack-exchange* posts about a similar thing but none of them work for me.

I am on linux btw if that is significant.

```
public Process runCommand(String command) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", command, "-S");

        Process process = pb.start(); // Executes the command
        return process;
    }

    public void showCommandOutput(Process process) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 

        String line = ""; // Empty String to put the output in
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // For every line in the shell output
                System.out.println(line); // Print the line
            }
            try {
                process.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // If this goes wrong, display stack trace
            } finally {
                quitServer(0); // External function for closing program, self explanatory
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"I am making a simple GUI interface .."* OK, but that has nothing to do with the problem at hand. Please don't add tags unless they're directly related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are halfway there already. The `Process` object that is returned when you called `pb.start()` contains the input and output streams you need to communicate with the external program. You are already reading from the `process.getInputStream()` to get the output of the process. To send it input, you simply need to write data to the `process.getOutputStream()` stream.

You should watch out when using `readLine()` with a process like bash. When bash writes the command prompt out, it does not end it with a newline (so you can enter your command on the same line). So your `readLine()` will wait forever for the newline which isn't coming. You probably want to use unbuffered reads and inspect the data for anything that looks like a prompt.

If you know for certain that your program will output text, expect a response, and then read in your input, you can perform this in your existing loop. Supplying a command after you read each line that you detect is a prompt. For example:

```java
    PrintStream commandWriter = new PrintStream(process.getOutputStream());
    while ((line = reader.read()) != null) { // For every line in the shell output
      // if I know prompts end with a certain substring
      if (line.endsWith("$> ")) {
        commandWriter.println("echo \"this is a command I sent to a process\"");
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Received from process: " + line);
      }
    }
```

But if the program you are interacting with is more interactive, you will probably want to start up separate threads to read and write the input/output. You have to be careful with the processes to make sure you keep reading data from them when it's available. If you forget to do that, the external program can hang when it gets stuck on a full buffer.